# Setting Firebase Firestore security rules so only users can CRUD their own data and all else is ignored

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I have an app that is designed so authenticated users via Google only have access to their own data with no "social" features. I want to know the security rules for the below criteria.

Let's say I have 5 collections and one of them is called "todos" and the data mirrors the other collections in that it has a field for the authenticated users uid. The typical document looks something like this:

**Todos**

```
todo:{
  title:"some titled",
  body:"we are the world , we are the children",
  uid:"2378y4c2378rdt2387btyc23r7y"  
}
```

**Some other collection**

```
thing:{
  name:"some name",
  content:"Some content",
  whatever:"whu-eva",
  uid:"2378y4c2378rdt2387btyc23r7y"  
}
```

I want the authenticated Google user to be able to CRUD any data that has said users uid in the  uid field. I want all other data to be inaccessible to the logged in user.

I want to know how to create rules for this scenario.

I'm mulling through the documentation now but I figure I might be able to save some time by asking.
I do not have specific roles for the app.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access

As a side note, is their a feature in Firebase to automatically bind an authenticated Google users uid to documents created while they are logged in? (I am assuming the answer is no and I was planning on manually grabbing the uid in my app and setting it on the client prior to document creation).

Thank you.

Update

I tried using the code that Klugjo posted below.

When I try to test it in the simulator I get an error.

Here is my collection and a screenshot of the error.

[image]

[image]

Here is something else I tried:
[image]

Based on everything I've read it seems like the following code should work -  but it doesn't. I've supplemented the key "userId" in place of " uid" that is written in the object data at the top of this post. I changed the key to distinguish it from the uid.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /todos/{id} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId;
    allow create, update, delete:
        if request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
      }
    }
  }
```

I've created a video where I try to GET and CREATE a document.
I don't think I am using the testing feature correctly.

**Video**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7GZNxmBCBo&feature=youtu.be

**EDIT**

I have it working when I test with a hard-coded `request.auth.uid`.
In the image below I hardcoded "test" as the `request.auth.uid`.

My problem now is that I would really like to know how to test it in the rules editor without hard-coding this information.

[image]

**Edit**

Here is a video demo of the problem using a real app.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8qctcpKd4Y&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Hi, William. You cant make this working with changing rules. I recommend using the firebase functions. So in function, you can get uid of account, and get all todo lists and filter by uid. Anyway client cannot get all todo lists and they will get only filtered data.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a sample secure rule set for your requirements.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{id}/{u=**} {
      allow read, write: if (isSignedIn() && isUser(id));
    }

    match /todos/{id}/{t=**} {
      allow read, write: if (isSignedIn() && isUserOwner());
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }



    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    function isUser(uid) {
      return uid == request.auth.uid;
    }

    function isUserOwner() {
      return getResourceData().uid == request.auth.uid;
    }

    function getResourceData() {
        return resource == null ? request.resource.data : resource.data
    }

  }
}
```

All documents are publicly inaccessible.

The rests will be decided based on the data already saved in DB and / or the data being sent by the user. The key point is `resource` only exists when reading from DB and `request.resource` only exists when writing to DB (reading from the user).

Documents under `todos` can be read and written only if they have a saved `uid` which is the same as the sent request's `uid`.

Documents under `users` can be read and written only if their document id is the same as the sent request's `uid`.

`isSignedIn()` function checks if request is authorised.

`isUser(id)` function checks if id matches the authorised request's uid.

`isUserOwner()` function checks if document's uid matches the authorised request's uid.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is the "resource" parameter in the security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation

Try something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /todos/{id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:

### Subcollection strategy

If you change your DB to look like the following:

`/users/{userId}/todos/**`

then you could allow users to read/write anything under their own document with the following rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid}/{doc=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

This would have the advantage of not needing to introspect the contents of the data which I believe might count against your read quota.

Comment: However I would consider a different strategy and have a `users` collections with a `userId` document and a `todos` subcollection. This way you can simply allow users to read/write to their collection.

Comment: Btw I think I might need instructions on how to test for your example because no matter what I do I get errors. In this case the resource object is null. The error is: "Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [4], column [49]. Null value error.". I haven't tried it in the actual app - I will do that now.

Comment: I just tried it in the app - it doesn't work. Thanks for trying

Comment: Take a look at the edit for the subcollections strategy. This is what I use with slight modifications so hopefully it works for you as well.

Comment: I'm playing with it now. I'll post later tonight. Thank you!

Comment: My app will have users log in with their google account. Using your strategy means I will need to "create" the user in the database in addition to using the google log in - correct? Assuming the answer is "yes", then that means I will need to write conditional code to check if a user with the uid already exists in the database and if it doesn't, then I will need to create it. Every subsequent log in by that user will require a conditional to check if they already have an account. If you can, let me know if this is true.

Comment: If you are using firebase authentication then they will have an internal `uid` upon registration. Try to go to the firebase authentication page and check to see if the user in your demo has a uid?

Comment: Yes, of course they have a uid, but I don't see how that relates to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214223/discussion-between-gustavo-hoirisch-and-william).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this

```
service.cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /todos/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

`match /todos/{userId}` makes the `userId` variable available in the rule condition

`request.auth.uid` matches the auth'd user `uid`

Comment: I've been playing with some similar code and I can't get the tests to work. I'll watch the video and get back.

Comment: I tried your code and I couldn't get it to work in the emulator. I edited my post above with screenshots. I watched the video.

Comment: Changed it around a bit, based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. Should I be doing a get request or should I be doing a document creation request to test? I want to verify both

Comment: I have modified the answer so that all options should be allowed

Comment: Your code allows me to create new documents when I am logged in but it does not let me "GET" documents. I get a rejection error.

Comment: From everything that I've read this SHOULD be the answer , but it doesn't work.   service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /todos/{id} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId;
    allow create, update, delete:
        if request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
      }
    }
  }

Comment: yeah it works well for me on my 2 apps .... Maybe check that the ids and id names match properly

Comment: I added a link to a video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7GZNxmBCBo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: your `userId` is empty in your todo document so you can't read data. Then when you save the document, you need to send the matching `userId` in the payload -> `Build Document` button

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I understand the userId key value is empty but I did that intentionally because the default request.auth.uid is empty. I am not sure what I am supposed to do with the build document button. If you want to edit your answer above based on the video I added to the question it would help. It would be easier to read instead of comments. Btw - thank you for this!

Comment: I edited my post above. I have it working when I hard code the request.auth.uid. My problem now is that I don't know how to test the rules without hardcoding that information. Any idea? Thanks again

Comment: I posted another video to demo exactly where I'm at:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8qctcpKd4Y&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thanks for the video, I have updated my answer. I think the last bit you are missing is: use `match /todos/{userId}` instead of `match /todos/{id}` since the name of the property is `userId` and not `id`. Then in the rule you can use the `userId` directly -> `if request.auth.uid == userId;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214146/discussion-between-william-and-klugjo).